# Uptime in Telegram bot in Python

Tags: python-2.7, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm playing with a Telegram bot sitting on my Raspberry Pi, all works good but I'm trying to show the uptime of the rpi with the command /uptime without success, I tried with:

```
elif command == '/uptime':
   bot.sendMessage(chat_id, os.system("uptime"))
```

or with

```
elif command == '/uptime':
  uptime = os.system("uptime")
  bot.sendMessage(chat_id,'%s' % uptime )
```

This is now my last, unsuccessful, attempt:

```
elif command == '/uptime':
   uptime = os.popen("awk '{print $1}' /proc/uptime").readline()
   bot.sendMessage(chat_id, ('uptime(sec) = '+uptime))
```

Where is the mistake?

Here is the complete code:

```
import sys
import os
import telepot
import datetime
import time
from datetime import timedelta

id_a = [111111,2222222,3333333,4444444,5555555]

def handle(msg):
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg['text']
    sender = msg['from']['id']


    print 'Got command: %s' % command

    if sender in id_a:
     if command == '/ciao':
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Hei, ciao!')
     elif command == '/apri':
         os.system("sudo python /home/pi/tg/xyz.py")
         bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Ti ho aperto!')
    elif command == '/uptime':
       with open('/proc/uptime', 'r') as f:
        usec = float(f.readline().split()[0])
        usec_str = str(timedelta(seconds = usec))
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, '%s' % usec_str)
    elif command == '/riavvia':
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Rebooting...')
            os.system("sudo reboot")
    else:
       bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Forbidden access!')
       bot.sendMessage(chat_id, sender)

bot = telepot.Bot('myToken')
bot.message_loop(handle)
print 'I am listening ...'

while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Tried also:

    elif command == '/uptime':
        uptime = subprocess.check_output(['uptime'])
        print '', uptime
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, str(uptime))

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the output from the `subprocess`. This is because in other cases Python casts the first value of the `stdout`.
The code to get the uptime should be like this:

```
import subprocess    
direct_output = subprocess.check_output('uptime', shell=True)
```

This will give you the uptime in the `direct_output` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
from datetime import timedelta

with open('/proc/uptime', 'r') as f:
    usec = float(f.readline().split()[0])
    usec_str = str(timedelta(seconds = usec))
    # and send message usec_str
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing, here how I modified:

   elif command == '/uptime':
       with open('/proc/uptime', 'r') as f:
        usec = float(f.readline().split()[0])
        usec_str = str(timedelta(seconds = usec))
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, '%s' % usec_str)

Comment: @fdicarlo What does your send message function or bot object look like?